# saving UIViews with userDefaults

Tags: swift, uiview, save, nsuserdefaults

I have a project where I put a view, a button to hide the view, one to show the view and then a label and a button (each time you press the button you get a number different from 0)

```
@IBAction weak var myView: UIView!
@IBAction Weak var myLabel: UILabel!
 var numbers: [Int] = [1, 7, 9, 6, 0, 3, 10, 45, 2, 83].shuffled()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView.isHidden = true
      myLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Key"))"


    }

 @IBAction func closeView(_ sender: Any) {
myView.isHidden = true
myLabel.text = 0
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "Key")
}

 @IBAction func showView(_ sender: Any) {
myView.isHidden = false
}

 @IBAction func addNumber(_ sender: Any) {
 let oneNum = numbers.shuffled().first

 UserDefaults.standard.set(oneNum, forKey: "Key")
            myLabel.text = "\(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Key"))"
}
```

What I want is to add a function that allows me to automatically show myView if the label displays a number different from 0. How can I do?

Comment: Can't you use an if statement in the `addNumber` method? `if oneNum != 0 { myView.isHidden = false }`

Comment: Don't understand why you're using UserDefaults here? A side point. Unsure I understand the question either? You want to replace the show/hide buttons? Where does the automatic come into play here?

Comment: @Sweeper already tried, doesn't work

Comment: @user3069232 because each time i go back to the menu I want the label to keep displaying the number I had before of leaving the vc. How could you understand I want to replace the buttons? I clearly said that I want my UIView to keep displaying after I reopen the "app" IF numOne is different from 0. easy

Comment: So to be clear what you want is when you press the button and 'addNumber' is executed you want hide the view if the number is zero and show it not.  Then what you also want is that when you restart the app it checks what the number is and shows or hides the view appropriately.

Comment: No i don't want to hide the view when i press addNumber, when I press it I just want the label to display a random number and i archived that right now. by the way yes, I want it to check the number and if it's different from 0 to display the view, if it's 0 it has to be hidden

Comment: Ok, so when you navigate away from the view and return, you want the view to still be showing the same number and also retain the showing/hidden status of the view?  Is that right?  Second, are you talking about when you EXIT the APP and relaunch it, or simply when you are navigating around in the app?

Comment: I didn't say you wanted to hide the view when you press the button I said when you press the button the number changes and only if the number is zero is the view hidden.  Then you want that to persist when you restart the app.

Comment: yes I want it to keep showing the view if the label has a different number from 0. Yes when i navigate in the @drewster

Comment: yes but i don't want to hide the view when i press something, even if I press the button and it gives me 0 I want my view to remain. I want it to be hidden only if the number is 0 and I leave the vc @UpholderOfTruth

Comment: Ok so you could use the `viewWillLoad` method and check the user defaults there to determine if it is zero.  Of course because you are not checking it when a button is pressed then it will be visible if 0 until you leave and hidden when you return because there will be no way to tell the difference.

Comment: ok perfect but how can i create a function where i add the user defaults to my view? because I managed to do that for labels, textfields but i really don't know how to do that since i can only create outlets and not actions with uiViews

Comment: and, wait you mean viewWillAppear right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
var numbers: [Int] = [1, 7, 9, 6, 0, 3, 10, 45, 2, 83].shuffled()

var currentNumber: Int {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(currentNumber, forKey: "currentNumberKey")
        myLabel.text = "\(currentNumber)"

        // Hide if number is 0, else show
        myView.isHidden = currentNumber == 0
    }
}

private func setNextNumber() {
    currentNumber = numbers.shuffled().first!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentNumber = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "currentNumberKey")
}

@IBAction func closeView(_ sender: Any) {
    currentNumber = 0
}

@IBAction func showView(_ sender: Any) {
    myView.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func addNumber(_ sender: Any) {
    setNextNumber()
}
```

Setting the variable ***currentNumber*** will automatically update the label text, and automatically hide myView (if currentNumber is zero) or show myView (if currentNumber is non-zero).

***viewDidLoad*** restores the state.  The state is maintained automatically if the UIViewController disappears and appears, so nothing is needed in ***viewWillAppear***/***viewDidAppear*** and ***viewWillDisappear***/***viewDidDisappear***.